# C# Active Directory Query sAMAccountname returning array of numbers instead of String

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, active-directory

I have a really strange thing happening on my site and I cant figure it out.

I have an auto complete box that queries an LDAP connection. The connection works fine and I get responses from the LDAP Query. BUT, here is where the problems start.

On my local machine, I get the response:

```
[{"label":"TestUser, Bill","value":"Testuesr, Bill","AdLogon":"bill.testuser"}]
```

but on my server I get the response:

```
[{"label":"TestUser, Bill","value":"Testuesr, Bill","AdLogon":[67,111,108,109,95,67]}]
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be starting this?

**Update**
If I change the AppPool from AppPoolIdentity to NetworkService then it returns the proper values.

Comment: Does "Colm_C" have some sens in your code context ?

Comment: Are those typo's suppose to be there..? Testuesr

Comment: Sorry about the typo, i was typing without thinking slip of the fingers @DJKRAZE

Comment: @JPBlanc Yes it does, thank you so much, I spent so long looking at the permissions that I never thought it was returning an ASCII Value Array of the sAMAccountName. I will know this from now on.

Comment: @Qpirate, I try to give some explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"67,111,108,109,95,67" is the integer array for "Colm_C", It's so becaise of the special catacter '_' . If think that an underlying layer need to transform sAMAccountName in a B64 string and it's then given back as an array.